# Calculating an equation solution in C++

Tags: c++, c, equation, algebra

I have a function in C++ with the following signature:

```
float Foo(float time, float min, float curr, float beta)
```

Within the function, I want to determine and return MAX in the following equation:

```
time = beta + (1.0f - beta) * ((MAX - curr) / (MAX - min))
```

To test the results, you could use the following arguments:

```
Foo(0.95f, 625, 800, 0.75f)
```

It should return 1500.

---

On paper, I have the steps needed to determine MAX, but I don't know how to get that working in code. If anyone can provide the code to perform this calculation, I would be extremely grateful.

```
0.95 = 0.75 + (1 - 0.75) * ((max - 800) / (max - 625))
0.95 = 0.75 + 0.25 * ((max - 800) / (max - 625))

0.95 - 0.75 = 0.25 * ((max - 800) / (max - 625))
0.2 = 0.25 * ((max - 800) / (max - 625))

0.2 / 0.25 =  (max - 800) / (max - 625)
0.8 = (max - 800) / (max - 625)

0.8 * (max - 625) = max - 800
(0.8 * max) - (0.8 * 625) = max - 800
(0.8 * max) - 500 = max - 800

((0.8 * max) - max) - 500 = -800

((0.8 * max) - max) = -800 + 500
((0.8 * max) - max) = -300

-0.2 * max = -300

max = -300 / -0.2

max = 1500
```

Comment: To get that working in code, start over, but don't replace the variables with numbers. Solve it exactly the same way, and you'll have your answer. (Or use a symbolic math program to do it for you.)

Comment: This sounds a lot like a home work question... so I don't want to say too much, but basically you need to rearrange the equation so that it is `Max = ...`

Comment: This sounds like "do my homework for me". Replace your numbers with names. Find expression for 'max'. Code it up.

Comment: ...or let Armen do the work for you. That works too, I guess.

Comment: @Alf, @Jefromi: Again, I don't believe this is homework, and I believe that the OP won't just copy-paste the code, but will think through the solution and will be able to deal with similar problems in the future. This may be naive approach, but I really hope I am right. I trust people

Comment: You keep saying C++, yet tag the question with C. Why? You're programming in one or the other, pick.

Comment: Thank you for the all responses.  For those that were concerned that this was a homework assignment, I assure you it wasn't. I haven't received an assignment like this for nearly 20 years, which is why it was giving me trouble. I'm a technical designer/artist, not a hard core programmer. I tagged the question with C because I assumed someone with knowledge of C (but not C++) might be of assistance. I tagged with C++, because that's the code-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
time = beta + (1.0f - beta) * ((MAX - curr) / (MAX - min))
```

let's denote time with t, beta with b, curr with c, min with m, and MAX with x;
we have

```
t = b + (1-b)(x-c)/(x-m)
(x-c)/(x-m) = (t-b)/(1-b)
(x-m)(t-b) = (x-c)(1-b)
x(t-b) - x(1-b) = m(t-b) - c(1-b)
x(t-1) = m(t-b) - c(1-b)
x = (m(t-b) - c(1-b))/(t-1)
```

so your function will be like this

```
float Foo(float time, float min, float curr, float beta)
{
   return (min*(time-beta) - curr*(1-beta))/(time-1);
}
```

I would also recommend refraining from using the identifiers `min` and `time`, because they may cause clashes with `std::min` and `std::time`

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them. They don't learn anything from it. In general, when they graduate and get a job, will be burden on co-workers.

Comment: @Armen: question itself is dead giveaway. "You can use ... to check" is just the 110% confirmation. Uh, additionally, anyone able to set up that exposition would have no problem doing the coding. Cheers

Comment: @Alf: This wasn't homework, I'm not a programmer, and I graduated years ago. My intention was to provide a concise question that wouldn't require followup or additional details. I provided the answer and test arguments, which I generated in Excel, so that they could be used in verifying the results.

Comment: @Armen: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm still looking over each step you provided, and while I'm not sure I understand exactly what's going on, the final result works.  Part of the problem I ran into when implementing the steps I provided is that I was trying to use multiple statements for the steps, and storing the intermediate results in variables.  As far as I know, you can't move an unknown variable value to the other side of the equal sign across multiple statements.

Answer (score 3):

On the paper multiply each part of the equation on `(MAX - min)`, then regroup elements to get `MAX=some`.
The paper and the pencil is what you usually need before writing C++ functions like in your question.